# Error with dcast function

Tags: r

I have a df in `long` format. Here is a sample:

```
       Dates   Names      Point.Forecast
1 2000-03-01 MSCI ACWI     0.16309946
2 2000-04-03 MSCI ACWI     0.21412161
3 2000-05-01 MSCI ACWI     0.04679327
4 2000-03-01 DJGlbl        0.1810070
5 2000-04-03 DJGlbl        0.1293746
6 2000-05-01 DJGlbl        0.7411549
7 2000-03-01 IBOXX         0.2861171
8 2000-04-03 IBOXX         0.25387063
9 2000-05-01 IBOXX         0.29944246

str(df)
'data.frame':   3408 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Dates         : chr  "2000-03-01" "2000-04-03" "2000-05-01" "2000-06-01" ...
 $ Names         : chr  "MSCI ACWI" "MSCI ACWI" "MSCI ACWI" "MSCI ACWI" ...
 $ Point.Forecast: num  0.1631 0.2141 0.0468 -0.1833 0.252 ...
```

I would like to convert it to `wide` format so it would look like:

```
 Dates        MSCI ACWI      DJGlbl         IBOXX 
2000-03-01    0.16309946     0.21412161     0.04679327
2000-04-03    0.1810070      0.1293746      0.7411549
2000-05-01    0.2861171      0.25387063     0.29944246
```

I get an `error`:

```
dfd=dcast(df,Dates~Names,value.var="Point.Forecast")

Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
```

Any suggestions?

Best Regards

Comment: Maybe follow the instructions given in the warning message and provide a more suitable aggregation function? (Look at `?dcast` at the arguments you can pass...)

Comment: I guess you mean that I need to pass `fun.aggregate` to dcast? But I dont know what a suitable fun.aggregate would be...

Comment: When there's just one (numeric) observation per combination of levels I typically use `sum`.

Comment: Ooh sorry... Found the error now... Made an error in Excel (Instead of  one variable name for a variable called Rusell 1000, Excel made it Rusell 1000, Rusell 1001, Rusell 1002 and so on..) dcast works now without fun.aggregate now, but thanks anyway!

Comment: @user1665355, can you edit your question so that the actual cause of the problem becomes visible, and then post your own answer indicating that this is the cause here? That way, others could benefit from a question which otherwise would be a candidate for a too-localized question.